# matplotlib.finance.quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc vs. quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl

Tags: matplotlib

Can anyone explain the difference between matplotlib.finance.parse_yahoo_historical_ochl and matplotlib.finance.parse_yahoo_historical_ohlc? What do ohlc and ochl stand for?
The documentation at http://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html is not particularly helpful in this regard.

Comment: 'open-high-low-close' vs 'open-close-high-low' .  Compare the function signatures.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I surmise ohlc corresponds to [Open-high-low-close_chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart), o -> opening, c ->closing, h->high and l ->low.